# DOM (Events) in GWT

Tags: javascript, dom, gwt, dom-events

I have a bit of a trouble understanding GWT's architecture. I can see two packages: `com.google.gwt.dom.client` and `com.google.gwt.xml.client`. As far as I understand, the first gives a wrapper for the HTML DOM and the second is for own DOM Documents. Is this correct?

What I need is an own Document (i.e. not the HTML Document) with Mutation Events. What would I use in this case? Is this possible in GWT or do I have to write my own DOM implementation, based on `com.google.gwt.xml.client`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[com.google.gwt.dom.client Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/dom/client/package-summary.html)* :

> Classes for low-level DOM programming. This package contains classes that expose the W3C standard HTML document object model for programmatic access and manipulation of HTML pages directly in client-side Java source, accounting for most browser variations. These classes provide an efficient, type-safe, and IDE-friendly alternative to writing JavaScript Native Interface (JSNI) methods for many common tasks

*[com.google.gwt.xml.client Javadoc](http://www.ing.iac.es/gwt-linux-1.4.60/doc/javadoc/com/google/gwt/xml/client/package-summary.html)* :

> Basic classes used in XML DOM parsing and XML document generation.
>   The classes in this package support parsing XML documents and creating new XML documents. The implementation uses the underlying browser.

Briefly, dom.client package is html parser (manipulation of HTML pages) and xml.client is for parsing XML documents. In your situation you can use gwt xml parser and here is good example for it [xml parser in gwt](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/gwt/retrieving-xml-data.shtml)

Comment: Okay, i.e. I cannot use gwt.dom.client for custom documents? And since there aren't any events in gwt.xml.client, I have to write my own implementation.

Comment: you cann't use gwt.dom.client for custom documents. yes